# Creating a hash of 100 things with random values for each value

Tags: ruby, iterator, hash

I'm building a hash that has 100 items and I also have a random number generator that generates 100 random values between 0 and 100.

I want to iterate through my numbers, 0..100 in consecutive order and assign them to the keys of the hash.

Then I want to iterate through the 100 random numbers and assign them to the values of the hash.

```
hash = {}
(0..100).each {|e| puts e} #just prints out the values
@numbers = 100.times.map{ 0+Random.rand(0..100)}
```

That's what I've got so far. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash = {}
100.times {|n| hash[n]=rand(101)}
```

The first line will initialize the empty hash (as you did above). The second line assigns 0 to 99 as keys to the hash, and random values between 0 and 100.

`times` is a method belonging to the Integer class. Given a block, it will pass in each successive integer `n` times.

Comment: With this you can get the same number multiple times. If I understand the question correctly he only wants every number between 1 and 100 once.

Comment: @Mischa: That's right. I wasn't able to determine from the question whether duplicate values would be acceptable. If not, then your solution is correct.

Answer (score 6):

```
h = {}
a = (1..100).to_a
100.times { |i| h[i+1] = a.delete_at(Random.rand(a.size)) }
```

Or:

```
keys = (1..100).to_a
vals = keys.shuffle
hash = Hash[keys.zip(vals)]
```